# SeparatorMenuItem not displayed

Tags: javafx, menu, fxml, separator

Why is my `SeparatorMenuItem` not displayed in the `Menu`?

```
  <MenuBar>
    <menus>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="DasChat">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="ExmapleMenuItem" />
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Abmelden" />
          <SeparatorMenuItem/>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Schließen" />
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="ExmapleMenuItem" />           
        </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Hilfe">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Über DasChat" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
    </menus>
  </MenuBar>
```

This is how i load the FXML:

```
Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Client.fxml"));
loader.setController(new ClientController(primaryStage));
try
{
    final Parent root = loader.load();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style/daschat.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setTitle("DasChat");
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/icon.png")));
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setIconified(false);
    primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Logging stuff
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Bug in Application]

, the `SeparatorMenuItem` should be between

> Abmelden

and

> Schließen

I have no `Separator` / `SeparatorMenuItem` styles applied.
I don't know if that matters at all, but `SeparatorMenuItem` isn't documented in the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you extend it to a [MCVE], in case you are doing something strange between the FXML and the actual application that is causing the separator not to appear. (Also, add a third menu item without a separator, see if there's really a difference...)

Comment: @James_D I have edited the Question.

Comment: @ScriptKiddy: This is neither minimal nor verifiable. To fix that please add controller+css, if necessary to reproduce the problem or remove them from the code. If controller/css are necessary, remove all the parts from them, that aren't necessary. If setting the icons is unnecessary, remove the line from the code. Do the same with the `Stage` title, iconified/maximized state ect.. Also adding information about the JVM + OS you're using could help. Just loading the above fxml with imports added and without a controller/css ect. results in the desired appearance for me BTW.

Comment: @fabian Thanks to your comment i got an idea what it could be, solved thanks. I didn't want any borders in my application, i didn't know the separator was just a one sided border (which i think is kind of stupid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem did lie in my css file:

```
*
{
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-border-width: 0 !important;
}
```

setting the `-fx-border-width` to

> 0

has caused the `SeparatorMenuItem` to be "gone".